# Header() redirect shows up in network activities but redirect isn't occuring

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am building a process where if I user lands on the home page, I check whether there is a valid cookie with a particular name. If the cookie doesn't exist, the user is redirected to `login.php`.

I do a `POST` request to a third party API to authenticate the user using AJAX and a PHP proxy to bypass any CORS issues. I get a response with an authToken upon successful authentication. I use this to create a token with the authToken (I don't have to worry about security issues and specifically need to use cookies). I then redirect the user back to the home page.

However, while I see the redirect happening in my network activities, more specifically a `GET` request is done to the url with a 200 status, the actual page is not rendered on my browser so the redirect isn't actually happening. I am not getting any error on my console or terminal.

Here is my code from the home page, redirecting to login:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_COOKIE['authToken'])){
    header ("location: /login.php");
  } 
?>
```

The AJAX `POST` request when the user attempts to login:

```
    const submitButton = document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0];
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
        const emailAddress = inputs[0].value
        const password = inputs[1].value        
        manageState().validateState();
        data = {
            name:'***',
            password: '***',
            userID: ***,
            userSecret: ***
        }
        console.log('data', data)
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "proxy.php?url=https://***/****",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: data,
            success: function (data){
                console.log('success', data)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The php proxy bypassing CORS issues:

```
function makePostRequest($baseURL) {
    global $redirect_url;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = http_build_query($_POST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
        $json = json_decode($response, true);
        createCookie($json['authToken']);
        header("Location: $redirect_url");
        exit();
    }
}
```

and the function, createCookie, creating the cookie:

```
function createCookie($token){
    global $redirect_url;
    $cookie_name = 'authToken';
    $cookie_value = strval($token);
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (20), "/"); //86400*30
}
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: I don't think you can do a header redirect from PHP code that is called by Ajax, can you? The output from the PHP code isn't sent to the browser, it's just returned to the calling JS code.

Answer (score -2):

What do you want to do? Redirection In PHP do like:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: /login.php");
```

But AJAX is not for redirecting by headers as is